# Where did I configure my termninal to execute this command on start?

Tags: macos, terminal, configuration

Months ago, I configured my terminal to execute the command `conda activate notbase` with each new session. This is what I see when I open a new terminal window:

```
conda activate notbase
Last login: Wed Apr 26 13:15:50 on ttys013
➜  ~ conda activate notbase
(notbase) ➜  ~
```

That was really convenient for the project I was working on at the time, but now I have multiple conda environments and don't want this to happen.

But I can't find where that command is set.

---

I'm running **MacOS Ventura 13.3**. I use [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) with [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh/). I've tried looking through every .*rc file in my home folder. I looked in .zprofile and .bash_profile. Nothing.

Then I ran `fgrep -Irs "conda activate notbase" ~/*` to search everything in my home directory tree. It found several files like this, but nothing more:

```
./Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20230419T173551/window1/exthost/output_logging_20230420T120336/1-Python.log:Send text to terminal: conda activate notbase
```

Where else can I look? What must I have done to make my terminal behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/*` will not search hidden files, so that's not going to get you what you want. Try this:

```
cd; ls -d *
```

See? No hidden files. I'm not sure where this line is, but it's most likely in your home directory somewhere. I encourage you to try [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which is crazy fast, and also makes searching recursively a breeze compared to grep.

```
rg --hidden "conda activate notbase"
```

A more OTT solution would be to add this to the top of your `~/.zshrc`:

```
set -x
```

This will spew everything that zsh does on startup. Hopefully your conda line will appear in there and you can figure out where it's hiding.

Comment: Oh wow! `rg` didn't find anything, so I used `set -x`. A line stuck out to me: `+omz_termsupport_preexec:8> cmdargs=( conda activate notbase )`. I googled "omz cmdargs" and found source code indicating this parameter was being passed to omz at the command line. After a minute of thinking, I realized the terminal app must be doing it. I found the problem in iTerm2's preferences, under Profiles > General > Command > "Send text at start". I deleted that field and the behavior stopped. Thank you for the help!